# How to get a RadioGroup list radiobuttons?

Tags: java, android, list, dynamic, radio-group

I created dynamically n RadioGroup, and every RadioGroup has m RadioButton. I saved this to a list, but i don't know how can i get the radiobuttons from my list.

I save the RadioGroups to my list like this:

```
List<RadioGroup> mylist = new ArrayList<RadioGroup>();
```

Comment: Why are you making list of `RadioGroup`? Make the list of `RadioButton`. And to get item from a `List`, use `get(position)` method of the list

Comment: Because i have a lot of radio group and i would like to save which radiobutton checked in the radiogroups to file

Comment: for each `RadioGroup` you will make many `RadioButton` ?

Comment: yes (i try to create a questionnaire application)

Comment: Okay. To get a particular `RadioGroup`, use this : `mylist.get(0);`. This will result the `ResultGroup` `Object` at `0` position

Comment: Thats okay, but how can i get the RadioButton? I try that: rb = (RadioButton) mylist.get(0); but its no good

Comment: nothing, i solved my problem!